# prepareForSegue push to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have a CollectionViewController with various cells. Every time I click on a cell I want to push to a view with a UIWebView inside of it. Each cell has a different URL.

I have managed to get the code to work but I'm getting this error: **Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'**

**Article.h**

```
@interface Article : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;

+ (void)articlesWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *articles, NSError *error))block;

@end
```

**Article.m**

```
@implementation Article

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.url = attributes[@"url"];

    return self;
}

+ (void)articlesWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *articles, NSError *error))block {
    [[DeadstockAPIManager sharedManager] GET:@"articles" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableArticles = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *attributes in JSON[@"articles"]) {
            Article *article = [[Article alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
            [mutableArticles addObject:article];
        }
        if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArticles], nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

**CollectionViewController**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showArticle"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
        Article *article = [self releaseForIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
        ArticleViewController *articleViewController = (ArticleViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        articleViewController.articleURL = article.url;
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *articleURL;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.articleURL]; **// This is where I get the error**
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Any other way I can achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your code like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.articleURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

`articleURL` is already of type `NSURL`, so no need to call `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.articleURL];`.

**Update:**
It seems you are putting an `NSString` into the `url` property of your `Article`.

Try the following in `Article.m`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *urlString = attributes[@"url"]; // first get the URL as a string from attributes
    self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; // then assign it to property of type NSURL

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: ah ok, well that means that what you are storing in `article.url` in `CollectionViewController` is actually an `NSString`. can you post the code for `Article.m` and also tell _where_ you assign `article.url`

Comment: and please update your question rather than posting it here in the comments :)